# How to make NestJS start even if one (or more) modules failed

Tags: nestjs

I have a NestJS app that connects to many services - RabbitMQ, Redis and TypeORM - postgres DB.
I want to make it so that even if, for example, the database connection can't be made, the app can still start and won't just crash...
Is that even possible?

Comment: I guess this is only feasible if you lazy load that module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Your NestJS app is crashing because the module or service connection is failing, and the exception is not being handled.

You can gracefully handle the exception with a simple `console.error("connection failed:", err)` message. This would allow the rest of the application to continue. Otherwise, if unhandled, the exception will halt the NestJS app from continuing.

### Handling Exceptions

Typically when you are connecting to service, it has an opportunity to fail. When it fails, it will `throw` an exception. Such as `throw new Error("this is the error");`

You can use try / catch blocks to handle these exceptions, so that the application can continue. [See this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) for an example of using try / catch to handle an exception.

```js
function getRectArea(width, height) {
  if (isNaN(width) || isNaN(height)) {
    throw new Error('Parameter is not a number!');
  }
}

try {
  getRectArea(3, 'A');
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
  // Expected output: Error: Parameter is not a number!
}
```

### Service Specific Error Handling

Check the documentation of the services you are connecting to. Their connection function may return a `Promise<t>` you can `await`. This can be wrapped in try / catch blocks.

Your service's connection function may also simply accept an error callback function. It is in this callback function where you can define to `throw` an error or to simply log the error to the console.

#### Example with NodeJS mssql package

The [mssql package connection function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connect-callback) accepts an error callback function. The provided function handles the error provided by the `err` parameter.

```js
pool.connect(err => {
    // This simple console error allows the app to continue.
    console.error("Error connecting to SQL service", err);

    // Using the following would re-throw the error and crash the app
    // throw err
})
```